# Android-show hidden divs in webdriver

Tags: javascript, java, android, html, webview

good day, my question is how do I do that android can show the divs that are hidden, I set the example for a better idea:
I have this HTML code:

```
<div style="display:none;">
<span id="streamurl">0EMd7omzeDE~1500255919~187.230.0.0~s26qzWq7</span>
</div>
```

This div is generated by javascript,
When I try to read the source code of the page, I print all the divs except for that.
This is my android code:

```
    class MyJavaScriptInterface
        {
            @JavascriptInterface
            @SuppressWarnings("unused")
            public void processHTML(String html)
            {
                Log.i("TAG", html);
            }
        }

        final WebView browser = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.browser);
       /* JavaScript must be enabled if you want it to work, obviously */
        browser.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        /* Register a new JavaScript interface called HTMLOUT */
        browser.addJavascriptInterface(new MyJavaScriptInterface(), "HTMLOUT");
        browser.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);

        /* WebViewClient must be set BEFORE calling loadUrl! */
        browser.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)
            {
        /* This call inject JavaScript into the page which just finished loading. 
      */
                browser.loadUrl("javascript:window.HTMLOUT.processHTML('<html>'+document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0].innerHTML+'</html>');");
            }
        });

/* load a web page */
        browser.loadUrl("https://openload.co/embed/FlPhcsBue-w?mime=true");
    }
```

I do not know what it can be, do you know some way to get that div, or more specifically, is there any way to get the direct download link from openload, from php or java?
Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

From the example you provided, it will not parse correctly because there is no ending div tag. It should be something like:

```
<div style="display:none;">
    <span id="streamurl">0EMd7omzeDE~1500255919~187.230.0.0~s26qzWq7</span>
</div>
```

This would definitely cause issues with any HTML parser since it doesn't know when the div tag ends.

Comment: im sorry, yes, this have close tag